# How to analyze data from a file using lists

Tags: python, list, data-analysis

[Heres what the program should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcBZc.png), [Here is the data file I am reading from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOxbs.png)I am creating a function that takes analyzes data from a file. The file consists of a sales persons ID number, the month they made a sale and the amount of the sale. I have to sort these into a 2-D list by quarter. I am having trouble finding a way to match the id number with the index and then adding the sales amount by quarter.

## This is the function that reads the ID numbers file, it works fine just showing the initialization.

```
def get_IDs(filename):
    idfile = open(filename, 'r')
    #create ID list
    id_list = []
    sales_data = []
    for line in idfile:
        id_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
        sales_data.append([0,0,0,0])
        id_list.sort()       
    idfile.close()       
    return id_list, sales_data
```

## This is the function that I am having trouble finding a way to set up. Each line of the file was split into the three pieces of information I just cant find a way to sort them.

```
def process_sales_data(filename, id_list, sales_data):
    datafile = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in datafile:
        data = line.split(' ')
        dataline = data[0] + data[1] + data[2]
        for salesperson in range(len(id_list)):
            for quarter in range(3):
```

Comment: give us an example input file and what you want the output to look like

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out how to optimize your code:

1. you don't have to read file twice, you can just do data process once, and store in the format your want.
2. sort by id is not necessary here, you can use dict to store four quarter amount by id.

Here is a sample code:

```
def process_sales_data(filename):
    sales = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            id, month, sale = line.strip('\n').split(' ')
            sales.setdefault(id, [0] * 4)[(int(month) - 1) // 4] += float(sale)
    return sales
```

If you want to output sorted by id, you can use `sorted` to dict.
Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )